# How can I split a comma-separated string, ignoring commas inside double quotes and parentheses?

Tags: perl

I want to split a comma-delimited parameter list into tokens, but I want to ignore the delimiter if inside double quotes or parentheses. For example:

```
my @arr = some_function('one, "string with ,", func(a,func2(1,2))');
```

should produce:

```
$arr[0] -> one
$arr[1] -> "string with ,"
$arr[2] -> func(a,func2(1,2))
```

I know that I can ignore the commas inside quotes with [`Text::ParseWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords), but that will still split `func(a,func2(1,2))` into multiple fields, since it's not quoted. Is there a clean way to do this, or do I have to write my own parser?

Comment: @MattJacob That will still split the function call into multiple fields since it's not quoted.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  I thought `extract_multiple` might do the trick, but I can't seem to get it working either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [Parse::RecDescent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RecDescent), which lets you define a grammar for parsing:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;
use Parse::RecDescent;
use Regexp::Common qw(balanced);

my $grammar = q{
    # One or more fields, separated by commas
    startrule     : field(s /,/)                                                        # / for broken Stack Overflow syntax highlighter

    # A field can be a function call, a double-quoted string, or bare text
    field         : func
                  | quoted
                  | bare

    # A double-quoted string. Returned with quotes stripped
    quoted        : /"[^"]*"/
                  {
                      $item[-1] =~ s/\A"|"\z//g;                                        # / for broken Stack Overflow syntax highlighter
                      $return = $item[-1]
                  }

    # "Bare" text: not a function call and not a quoted string. May contain
    # spaces
    bare          : /[^,]*/

    # A function name
    identifier    : /\w+/
};

$grammar .= qq{
    # A function call
    func          : identifier /$RE{balanced}{-parens=>'()'}/
};

$grammar .= q{
                  { $return = join '', @item[1..$#item] }
};

my $parser = Parse::RecDescent->new($grammar) or die 'Bad grammar';

my $parsed = $parser->startrule(
    'one two, "string with ,", func(a,func2(1,2))'
);
print Dumper $parsed;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'one two',
          'string with ,',
          'func(a,func2(1,2))'
        ];
```

Note that this does not handle quoted fields that contain escaped quotes, although that would be easy enough to add if you know which character is used for escaping.

Comment: This looks like it will do what I want in a much neater way than I've been using up until now.   I'll have to read up on it.  Thanks for pointing it out.